# Twilio: When conference created dial a client device into the call and make transfer to another phone

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-node

I'll explain what's the main idea... I have like a call center (made with node js and vue), my app has agents which will receive and make calls to contacts (outside people, clients), right now I can dial inbound and outbound calls. But I can't transfer the calls like that... so I decided to use Conference Verb, which actually works better as a call center, but now I can't even connect the call to my agent in my app.

```
// my incoming call now with a conference
const voiceResponse = new VoiceResponse();
  const dial = voiceResponse.dial()

  dial.conference({
    maxParticipants: 2,
    startConferenceOnEnter: false,
    waitUrl: 'https://twimlets.com/holdmusic?Bucket=com.twilio.music.soft-rock',
  }, `Conference of ${req.body.From}`);

  const client = dial.client(clientName)

  res.type('text/xml');
  res.send(voiceResponse.toString());
```

Is this also the same way when doing an outbound call to a client (not an agent).

Answer (score 0):

When making an outbound call, you can use the Conference /Participants resource to add the customer to a conference.

[Conference Participant Resource (Create Conference Participant)](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant-resource)

Comment: but that's using the Rest API, which in this case there is no way to make it automatically when building the conference call, is that right?